# update post meta front end

Tags: updates

Why doesent this work?!
I want to update my postmeta "doors" from frontend

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    { //if nonce check succeeds.
        global $post;
        $postid = $post->ID;
        $data = $_POST['doors'];
        update_post_meta($postid, 'doors', '2' );
        echo self::$auto_id. 'doors'.'2';
        echo $postid;

}


$doors = get_post_meta($auto->ID, 'doors', true);
?>

<form method="post" action="">
   <input type='text' name='doors' value='<?php echo $doors ?>' />
   <input type='submit' value='save' />
</form>
```

This code display the door value in my input but if i write something else there then click save nothing happends... it doesent save my new value.

Why?:(

Comment: you should try to echo out a value at the top of your `IF` statement to make sure that you're even getting inside the conditional. If that doesn't work, try to check if `doors` isset instead of submit

Comment: huuh? can u write an example, im not sure if i understand what u mean:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start debugging the problem. First let's make sure that we're getting into our `IF` conditional when the form `$_POST`s. If you replace your code with this, then submit your form, you should see the message *We've gotten into the $_POST conditional!"*

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
    echo "We've gotten into the $_POST conditional!"
    exit;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
   <input type='text' name='doors' value='<?php echo $doors ?>' />
   <input type='submit' value='save' />
</form>
```

According to your comment you did get into the $_POST conditional. So we can update the post meta.

```
<?php
    global $post;

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    {   
        if( ! isset( $post ) ) {
            echo 'Error: Post Object Not Set';
            die();
        }
        else if( ! isset( $_POST['doors'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['doors'] ) ){
            echo 'Error: Doors Not Set';
            die();
        }

        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'doors', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['doors'] ) );
    }

    $doors = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'doors', true);

    echo print_r($doors);
?>

    <form method="post" action="">
       <input type='text' name='doors' value='<?php echo isset($doors) ? $doors : ''; ?>' />
       <input type='submit' value='save' />
    </form>
```

If you don't receive any errors that means both `$post` is in scope and set and that `doors`  is also set and not empty. Which means that it should definitely update the post meta. If this doesn't work there could be problems outside of the code given.

Comment: Hey, im getting in the post in Case A then i followed your text but still, its update all field...

I am very thankful that your are trying to helping me out, do u have any other option?:)

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the door value in $data variable. But you're not using this variable in update_post_meta function.

All time you are save ing static value 2. You will update this line

```
update_post_meta($postid, 'doors', '2' );
```

with

```
update_post_meta($postid, 'doors', $data );
```

Also you wrote this code $doors = get_post_meta($auto->ID, 'doors', true); But how are getting $auto object. I think that your syntax will be

```
$doors = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'doors', true);
```

Comment: that didnt work.. :(

Comment: change this line <input type='submit' value='save' /> with <input type='submit' value='save' name="submit"/>

Comment: yes that works fine if i change $postid = $post->ID; to-> $postid = $auto->ID;

but a new problem came..., now it updated all my input on my dashboard like this http://i58.tinypic.com/2qtd5p4.png

Comment: are you change this line update_post_meta($postid, 'doors', '2' ); by update_post_meta($postid, 'doors', $data );

Comment: global $post;
            $postid = $auto->ID;
            $data = $_POST['doors'];
            update_post_meta($postid, 'doors', $data );

Comment: Can I get your site URL? Every post details page the form is coming? I think that you need to pass the post id as a hidden value in form and then data will update based on specific post ID.